# Issue in compiling the muPDF library

Tags: android, sdk, mupdf

I am getting the compilation issue in muPDf library for android.I am running ndk build in ubuntu_12.04.

```
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:5:35: fatal error: ../generated/cmap_cns.h: 
 No such file or directory compilation terminated.
 /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/build-binary.mk:269: recipe for target 
 `obj/local/armeabi/objs/mupdfcore/__/__/pdf/pdf_cmap_table.o' failed
 make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/mupdfcore/__/__/pdf/pdf_cmap_table.o] Error 1
```

if anyone have idea.Please reply.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed a step in the build process. The contents of the 'generated' folder need to be created on a host system I think, and copied to the target build. You should refer to this document http://www.mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android in particular the step "Populate the generated directory with the necessary files: "